# How to put a curly brace in the right of three lines within an align-environment

Tags: align, braces

I have a question concerning how to add a curly brace at the right side of three lines in an align-environment. The following is an example of what I'm speaking about:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amsfonts,amssymb, enumerate}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
&\rlap{\textbf{Optimization model}}
\nonumber \\
&                  && z=\sum_{i\in I} x_i\cdot y_i \cdot z_i \rightarrow \max
\nonumber \\
&\text{s.t.} && x_i \le b_i, 
             &  i\in I, \\
&            && x_i \le y_i,
             &  i \in I,  \\
&            && y_i \le z_i,
             &  i\in I,  \\
&            && z_i \le x_i,
             & i\in I, \\
&            && x_i, y_i, z_i \in \mathbb{R}_{+},
             & i\in I. 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

There are five lines of constraints (after the "s.t."). I would like to make a curly brace over the first parts of the second, third and fourth line (i.e. over x_i \le y_i, y_i \le z_i and z_i \le x_i) and write a single "i \in I" in the right of this brace. I hope it was possible to understand it.

Can you please tell my how to achieve this? (The general style of this align-environment should not be changed.)

PS: Here is a picture of how it should look like:
[image: curly brace in the right of the first parts of lines 2 up to 4]

Comment: I added a picture of how it should look like. (not very nice, but one should understand what is meant there)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With help of `mathtools` package you can use `rcases` environment.:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}% <-- new package for rcases

% for show just the equation ...
\usepackage[active,displaymath,tightpage]{preview}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}


\begin{document}
\begin{align}
&\rlap{\textbf{Optimization model}}
\nonumber \\
&                  && z=\sum_{i\in I} x_i\cdot y_i \cdot z_i \rightarrow \max
\nonumber \\
&\text{s.t.} && x_i \le b_i,                        &  i\in I, \\
&            && %\!\!% first approximation of  misalignment compensation ...
                \negthickspace% for compensation of rcases misalignment
                \begin{rcases}  
                x_i    \le y_i \\
                y_i    \le z_i \\
                z_i    \le x_i
                    \end{rcases}                    & i\in I, \\
&            && x_i, y_i, z_i \in \mathbb{R}_{+},   & i\in I.
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Hope that this is what you like to achieve.
[image]

*Edit:* 
Better alignment is achieved if you instead of `\!\`! you use `\negthickspace`. It is approximately `\mkern-5mu` as suggest Bernard in his answer. The picture is replaced with new, where this `\negthickspace` is used.  Use of `alignat` instead of align is probably more correct selection, but final result is the same.

Comment: You probably didn't notice, but the equations are slightly mis-aligned...

Comment: Yo', I nted this. I try (in hurry) to fix misalignment with \!. The result is not perfect ... but can be improved (I left this to OP). Later (when I will have more time) iI will return to this problem and try to find its cause.

Comment: How would you align the equations at the equals / not-equals sign? Not sure if this thread is still active after 6 years or if I should open a new one?

Comment: I'm still active here , however I do not understand your question. Ampersands in the `cases` in my answer are left out by purpose (that all  are aligned with equal sign). It will be better to ask new question and in it explain (with MWE), what is your problem.

Answer (score 3):

A slight improvement with the `alignedat` environment and a better alignment of the constraints:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}%

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{3}
&\rlap{\textbf{Optimization model}}
\nonumber \\
& & &z=\sum_{i\in I} x_i\cdot y_i \cdot z_i \mathrlap{\rightarrow \max} & &
\nonumber \\
&\text{s.t.}\qquad & &x_i \le b_i, & i\in I, \\
& && \mkern-5mu\begin{rcases}
 x_i \le y_i \\
 y_i \le z_i \\
 z_i \le x_i
 \end{rcases} & i\in I, \\
& && x_i, y_i, z_i \in \mathbb{R}_{+}, & i\in I.
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]