# Alignment problem with rcases in aligned environment

Tags: align

I want all equations to bo properly aligned along the '=' sign. But what I get is the following: Consider this MWE

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}  
\begin{align}
        \begin{aligned}
            a &= b + c + d\\
            e &= f\\
            \begin{rcases}
                g &= h\\
                i &= j  
            \end{rcases}
            \quad \forall k < l
        \end{aligned}
    \end{align} 
\end{document}
```

which produces this:
[image]

Is there a global solution to fix the alignment and get rid of the extra white space between the left expression and the '=' sign inside the rcases environment?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Related (but do not solve directly the problem): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361790/how-can-i-create-braces-around-aligned-equations  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223071/how-to-put-a-curly-brace-in-the-right-of-three-lines-within-an-align-environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following automates the spacing correction between the `rcases`-like construction and the rest of the `aligned` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newlength{\mylen}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \settowidth{\mylen}{$\displaystyle hijk = {}$\,}
  \begin{aligned}
    a &= b + c + d \\
    e &= g         \\
      &\phantom{{}={}}
      \hspace*{-\dimexpr\mylen+\nulldelimiterspace}
        \left.\begin{aligned}
          hijk &= l \\
             m &= n
        \end{aligned}\right\}
        \quad \forall k < l
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The idea is to set the `rcases`-like construction using `aligned` on the RHS of the equation alignment and then move it to the left exactly the right amount so the equality signs line up. `\mylen` is the correct length, equivalent to the longest LHS of the `rcases`-like construction, plus an appropriately-spaced `=` and `\,` (inserted by `aligned`).

Answer (score 1):

Here are three ways: with `\MoveEqLeft` from `mathtools` (by trial and error), with an `array` environment and the `bigdelim` package, and with `blkarray`.

*Unrelated*: needless to load `amsmath` when you load `mathtools`(or `empheq`). This is automatic.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{array, bigdelim}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
        \begin{aligned}
            a &= b + c + d\\
            e &= f\\
             \MoveEqLeft[0.8]\begin{rcases}
            \begin{aligned}
                g & = h\\
                i & = j
            \end{aligned}
            \end{rcases}
            \quad \forall k < l
        \end{aligned}
    \end{align}
\bigskip
\begin{equation}
        \begin{array}{r @{}>{{}}l@{}l}
            a &= \mathrlap{b+ c + d}\\
            e &= f\\
                g & = h & \,\rdelim\}{2}{*}[\quad$ \forall k < l $]\\
                i & = j
        \end{array}
    \end{equation}
\bigskip

    \begin{equation}
        \begin{blockarray}{r @{}>{{}}l}
            a &= \mathrlap{b+ c + d}\\
            e &= f\\
        \begin{block}{r @{}>{{}}l\Right{\}}{\quad$ \forall k < l $}}
                g & = h \\
                i & = j \\
        \end{block}
        \end{blockarray}
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With use of the `nicematrix` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,
                calligraphy}
\tikzset{
B/.style = {decorate,
            decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=4pt,
            raise=2mm},% for mirroring of brace
            thick,
            pen colour=black}
        }

\usepackage[active,displaymath, tightpage]{preview}% don't use in real document!
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    \setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
\begin{NiceArray}{RL}%
    [code-after={\tikz\draw[B]  (3-2.north east) -- 
                    node[right=7mm] {$\forall k < l$}
                                (4-2.south east);
                }
    ]
a & = b + c + d  \\
e & = f          \\
g & = h          \\
i & = j           
\end{NiceArray}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: for final looks you need to compile document at least twice.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind manually adjusting the spacing so that they line up correctly on the left, you can do as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}  
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        a &= b + c + d\\
        e &= f\\
          & \mkern-15mu \begin{rcases} \begin{aligned}
                g &= h\\
    i &= j  \end{aligned}
        \end{rcases}
        \quad \forall k < l
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

To keep the correct spacing, the interior of `rcases` is wrapped again in `aligned` so that the spacing between the terms are the same as outside the `rcases`. The whole thing is placed on the right of the alignment point, and then manually shifted back left so that the equals signs line-up. The amount of shifting of course depends on the actual expressions involved, so you will have to play with it by hand.